# Using jquery's parent function on an AJAX response

Tags: jquery

I am somewhat new to jquery and have no idea if this is possible, so here goes.

Basically, I am using an ajax get request, the result is in valid html, I already can select a specific object on the page that I want, and I want to then use that to get all of its siblings, this is how the code looks:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: requestUrl,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data, textStatus)
        {
            var allLinks = $(data).find("a");
            allLinks.each(function(){
                        if($(this).text() == 'selectme'){
                             $(this).parent().children("a").last().css('color', 'red');
                        }
                    });
              }
      });
```

This is what the response looks like:

```
<html>
<body>
   <a>irrelevant link 1</a>
   <div>
      <a>selectme</a>
      <a>sibling 1</a>
      <a>sibling 2</a>
      <a>last sibling, which I want to get</a>
   </div>
   <a>irrelevant link 2</a>
   <a>irrelevant link 3</a>
</body>
</html>
```

So, basically, I want to get the last sibling of the selectme link. Is it possible to make parent use the response instead of the actual page elements, and if not, how can I get the siblings without getting any of the irrelevant links? I could use the index of "selectme" to create a subselection, but how can I stop before "irrelevant link 2"?

Comment: I realize I can also use siblings("a") instead of parent().children("a").

Comment: In order to use jQuery you need to add the ajax response to the actual DOM structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try to add the response to the HTML document.

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'GET',
    url: requestUrl,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data, textStatus)
    {
        $('body').html(data); // jQuery works on actual DOM, not just a string
        var allLinks = $('body').find("a");
        allLinks.each(function(){
                    if($(this).text() == 'selectme'){
                         $(this).parent().children("a").last().css('color', 'red');
                    }
                });
          }
  });
```

Comment: Okay, so I am choosing this one because it was submitted first. I am adding the content to a div with display:none, and it's doing exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use last selector

```
$("div a:last-child")
```

i.e.

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: requestUrl,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data, textStatus)
        {
             $("div a:last-child").css('color', 'red');                
      });
```

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure that the parent will always be a div. This is the problem. I do not want it to break if I change the code in the future. Also, won't that work on the page itself? Instead of the response data?

Comment: Of course it will work on the page and not the response data. You have to either do the operation on the data attribute or insert it into dom before you try to find it in the DOM